# Is it possible to set number of records in flat file source in SSIS

Tags: ssis

There are two ways row sampling and percentage sampling ,but both loads all the data into the cache and then fetch a set of records from it.I m having 65 million records and no way to load all the data into cache.suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: have you considered using the bulkimport task instead of a dataflow to import all the records to a staging table? Then you could filter the records to just the  ones you want in your dataflow with a query.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no property to determine how many rows to read on the flat file connection manager.

Another approach might be to use a script component and use the System.IO (or similar) namespace to manually import your CSV file. In that script you could limit the amount of rows that are read. Google "read CSV file .NET".

Answer (score 0):

there isnt a direct way of doing that. You can try a work around method by using he "data rows to skip" property

[image]

you can create a randon numeric variable and set it to this property through configuration:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Diego ,while giving a large amount of data to skip,execution is hanging.